# Undefined index: App\LoginToken {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a LoginToken from the model App\LoginToken

Before it was working fine with Laravel 5.6

I have upgraded to the 8 and it stopped working.

I have tried looking for a syntax error i am doing but i am unable to resolve it

Here is the Code For **App\LoginToken.php**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Hash;

class LoginToken extends Model
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'creating_user',
        'token_hash',
        'expires_at',
    ];

    //Only available during the request the token was created in
    private $token;
    
    public static function boot() {

        self::creating(function($loginToken)
        {
            $loginToken->identifier = str_random(10);
            $loginToken->token = str_random(30);
            $loginToken->token_hash = bcrypt($loginToken->token);
        });
    }

    public function user() 
    {    
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);
    }

    public static function findValidToken($token)
    {
        $id = explode('_', $token)[0];
        $key = explode('_', $token)[1];

        $foundToken = static::where(['identifier' => $id])
            ->where('expires_at', '>', new Carbon())
            ->first();

        if(Hash::check($key, $foundToken->token_hash)) {
            return $foundToken;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->identifier . '_' . $this->token;
    }
}
```

**App\User.php** User Model With HasMany On LoginToken Model

```
public function loginTokens()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\LoginToken::class);
}
```

and here i am accessing it from the TokenController

```
use App\LoginToken;
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

$required_parameters = [
  'email',
];

if ($this->error_missing_parameter($data, $required_parameters)) {
    return $this->error_missing_parameter($data, $required_parameters);
}
$user = User::where('email', $data['email'])->first();

if (!$user) {
    return response()->json([
     'status' => 'not_found',
     'found' => 'false',
    ], 200);
}

$loginToken = User::loginTokens()->create([
  'creating_user' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id,
  'expires_at' => new Carbon('+5 minutes'),
]);
```

**Error.log**

```
[2021-03-15 05:59:46] development.ERROR: Non-static method App\User::loginTokens() should not be called statically {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Non-static method App\\User::loginTokens() should not be called statically at C:\\laragon\\www\\TurboPassPoiBetaC\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\LoginTokensController.php:51)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create an instance of User model in `TokenController`. `loginTokens()` method is not a static function so I think you should first create an instance of User model. it should be like below.

```
// Attention this line.
$user = new User();
$loginToken = $user->loginTokens()->create([
  'creating_user' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->id,
  'expires_at' => new Carbon('+5 minutes'),
]);
```